# Leaving the exact definition to the library client

Tags: c, declaration, extern

I'm working on an application consisting of multiple modules which are built as static libraries. It looks as

```
root
  |__module1
  |    |__mod1.h
  | 
  |__module2
  |    |__mod2.h
  |
  main.c
```

`mod1.h` (header guards omitted):

```
//returns 0 on success error code otherwise
int do_mod1();
```

`mod2.h` (header guards omitted):

```
//returns 0 on success error code otherwise
int do_mod2();
```

I defined error codes right in the library header:

`mod1.h`:

```
#define MOD1_ERROR 1
int do_mod1();
```

`mod2.h`

```
#define MOD2_ERROR 2 //1 can not be used otherwise it would introduce a conflict
int do_mod2();
```

The problem is there might be conflict between error codes across the modules introducing unnecessary dependencies between each other.

So I decided to introduce `extern` declaration, put error code in a separate header in the modules and provide a definition in the application which uses these modules. Something like this:

`mod1err.h`:

```
extern const int mod1_error;
```

`mod2err.h`:

```
extern const int mod2_error;
```

`application_error.h`:

```
#include mod1err.h
#include mod2err.h

const int mod1_error = 1;
const int mod2_error = 2;
```

Is it a good practice to use `extern` declarations this way or there might be a better approach??

Comment: What do you mean by "there might be a conflict between error codes across the modules"?

Comment: I don't really get why it's a problem that `do_mod2` should return `1` on error as well. Calling code knows it's calling `do_mod2`, and not `do_mod1`

Comment: @Melon if I define the same error codes for errors in different modules the client of both of modules cannot distinguish the error simply using its code.

Comment: @StoryTeller The problem will be if I try to propagate error down the call stack and handle it somewhere else. So this `extern` is for propagation purpose only (distinguish errors by their codes)

Comment: That won't be you, that will be the client. It's their choice is they want to distinguish the modules or handle it uniformally. And they have all the information they need even if both functions return 1.

Comment: Preprocessor directives are terminated by newline, not a semicolon. That semicolon in your macro definitions will be part of the macro expansion.

Comment: @StoryTeller You mean to allow the client to define its own error codes or error structure and and wrap into it a library error-code?

Comment: No, I mean don't over engineer a solution because of an imagined problem, YAGNI.

Comment: "Some Name" correct if I am wrong. If you are going to have functions mod_1 ... mod_256 so you will define diffirent error codes for each module? For example. you will have ```FILE_NOT_FOUND_MOD1 = 1``` and ```FILE_NOT_FOUND_MOD2 = 2``` ... ```FILE_NOT_FOUND_MOD256 = 256```.    What's the point? The client knows what function it is using, so there's no point for having separate error codes.

Comment: @Melon Sort of this. But for the specific file `FILE_NOT_FOUND` case I planned to declare it in all modules with the same name allowing them to link together or put it somewhere in a common `common_err.h`. So `modXXXerr.h` would have only module-specific error codes. Does it look weird or like overengineering?

Comment: Yes. Do you know ```errno```?

Comment: @Melon _Do you know errno?_ Sure, but I thought of abstracting away the POSIX-specific things like that. But probably that was the wrong direction...

Comment: I didn't mean to abstract away the POSIX-specific things, but how it is designed. Error codes are shared between system calls, library calls, etc. The error codes in one place.
Just imagine (in your scenario) if you want to add another error code to your module and you have to check if that error code is already used... That would be a clusterduck